# Does MSDN has syntax highligthing?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, syntax-highlighting, msdn

Reading the MSDN documentation in a web browser is a real pain because the absence of syntax highlighting. In those web pages, code spinets are surrounded by a div with `class="codeSnippetContainerCode"`.

I came across Sight, a chrome plugin. If you open a .js file it would show the syntax right. But it wont syntax highlight source code embedded in a page.

**EDIT**
Looks like [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5783457/how-to-add-syntax-highlighting-to-google-chrome)
has a good solution with Code Highlight chrome plugin.

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer instead.

Comment: I need 100 Reps for that. Code HighLight does not seems to work for MSDN.